# How do I change source directory in Dart/Pub config?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I couldn't find answer to this in Dart documentation.

[My application](https://github.com/lucperkins/dart-spray-akka-example)'s server-side is driven by Spray and by convention static files are stored in `/webapp` folder. When I try to build Dart project I get following error

```
C:\work\externals\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat build --mode=release
Your package must have a "web" directory, or you must specify the source directories.
```

How can I change it from `web` to `webapp` ? My `pubspec.yaml` looks like this

```
name:  dart_spray_example
description:  A sample Dart/Spray application

dependencies:
  browser: any
```

Here is layout of my application right now

[image]

Comment: Did you finalise the best way you got this to work? I'm using your template app and face the same issue, though I'm using IntelliJ to run pub

Comment: @byrnedo Priodically running `pub cache repair` helped but I had t odo that a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just pass it as an additional argument.

```
pub build --mode=release webapp
```

but I would expect troubles doing it this way because only some top-level directory names are compliant with the [pub package layout convention](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html).

```
pub build --mode=release example
```

would be fine.

It might be easier to just use `web` as the source directory and move the generated output to `webapp`. I'm aware that this can cause problems during development but I would expect it to be easier to fix the development setup instead of the build setup.

Using frameworks like Angular and Polymer which make heavy use of transformers have a strong dependency on the package layout convention.

Comment: You know renaming folder didn't help at all ! Looks like it's blaming other folder than I expected. Could you please take a look at my layout ? I added screenshot to the question.

Comment: The `web` directory has to be a subdirectory of the directory containing the `pubspec.yaml` file. You would need to move the `pubspec.yaml` file up  into the `main` directory.

Comment: I think the officially supported method in such environments is to integrate `pub serve` into your server application in a way that requests for Dart ressources are forwared to a locally running `pub serve` instance (only during development) and for production the output of `pub build` is just moved where it is expected by your app.

Comment: Looks like `pub` is gonna be another pain just like with `sbt`. Now I get following error `Cannot open file, path = 'C:\work\sideprojects\courierapp\zasutki_server\src\main\packages\browser\dart.js' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified., errno = 3)` even though file is there. What could it be ?

Comment: Is this from `pub build` or `pub serve`? Did you run `pub upgrade` after moving `pubspec.yaml` from the `main` directory?

Comment: It's from `pub build`. Actually after deleting `package` folder pub no longer fetches dependencies (main\packages\browser\ is empty). Nevertheless pub says `Resolving dependencies...
  browser 0.10.0+2
No dependencies changed.`

Comment: This seems to call for `pub cache repair` to repair a corruped cache directory. Can you please try to run this from you main directory. If it doesn't help delete the content of the `.pub-cache` directory (not sure what it's name and location is on windows but when you have symlinks in the `packages` directory they should point exactly to this pub cache directory.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I didn't think it would be so fragile. Thanks!

Comment: There are plans (for about a year or more already I guess) to get rid of the symlinks which cause a lot of troubles. But there are several dependencies not easy to get rid of. There seems to be another issue too, which causes the cache to become corrupt which is under active investigation. There were a lot of changes around pub the recent months and it works quite well besides this one bug. Until this is fixed: when you have weird issues with dependencies just call `pub cache repair` and if you have still issues clean the cache directory.